# Are UbuntuOne services coming to Kubuntu/KDE?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.04, kubuntu

Are UbuntuOne services coming to Kubuntu/KDE desktop in 11.04?

Answer (score 2):

No; I am aware of no efforts to deliver anything KDE-specific in 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [article](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/08/ubuntu-one-in-kubuntu-1010.html) I don't really know if the client work properly but you can give it  a try.